# I use pyinstaller to pack my python file. why there's always an error in 'import pymssql'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pymssql

I use pymssql to insert some data into my database, the code can run in pycharm, but when i use pyinstaller to pack this code into .exe, it always show error as the picture.
I run **pyinstaller -F update.py** in cmd.

*When i open .exe in cmd, it always show this error:*

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH4BX.png]

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried hidden imports if not run: 
**pyinstaller —hidden-import=pymssql filename.py**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running :

```
pyinstaller -onefile filename.py
```

Answer (score 0):

When i added

```
import pymysql
```

to the python-file - i was able to compile with pyinstaller and run the program.

(even that this import was NOT necessary in the initial python-program while i was running this from pycharm)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in pymssql 2.2.0. In my case helped me rollback to version 1.5.0